# Getting error "ErrImagePull" in kubernetes deployment in simple print hello world program

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes

**helloworld.java**:

```
import java.util.*; 
public class helloworld {
public static void main(String[] a)
{
    int index;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(index=0;index<20;index++)
    System.out.println("helloworld\t"+(index+1));
}
}
```

**Dockerfile.file**:

```
FROM openjdk:7
LABEL maintainer="Arun kumar"
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN javac helloworld.java
CMD ["java", "helloworld"]
```

This prepares a docker image, which I can then create using this command (in the repository where the files are present):
`docker built -t javaprogram .`

Then I run this image using this command:
`docker run -it -d javaprogram`

Then I create the copy of container using this command:
`docker commit containerId arunkumarduraisamy66/javacontprogram`

Then I push the image to my docker hub repository in public mode using this command:
`docker push arunkumarduraisamy66/javacontprogram`

Then I start MiniKube:
`minikube start`

Then I try to create a container using this command:
`kubectl create deployment javakubedeployment --image=arunkumarduraisamy66/javacontprogram`

It gives the following error: `ErrImagePull`

I am not sure how to resolve this.

```
C:\Users\thula\Documents\kubernetes and docker\docker java\helloworld> kubectl describe pod javaprogram-64b48854-ns7jp
Name:         javaprogram-64b48854-ns7jp
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.49.2
Start Time:   Wed, 30 Dec 2020 09:04:42 +0530
Labels:       app=javaprogram
              pod-template-hash=64b48854
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           172.17.0.3
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.3
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/javaprogram-64b48854
Containers:
  javacontprogram:
    Container ID:   docker://8cb0722bde94704a3dfbec2514958c1cea88bd0f5df0afb2678292835c4f871e
    Image:          arunkumarduraisamy66/javacontprogram
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://arunkumarduraisamy66/javacontprogram@sha256:fe00f09ebc6a6bc651343a807b1adf9e48b62596ddf9424abc11ef3c6f713291
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Wed, 30 Dec 2020 09:05:50 +0530
      Finished:     Wed, 30 Dec 2020 09:05:51 +0530
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Wed, 30 Dec 2020 09:05:16 +0530
      Finished:     Wed, 30 Dec 2020 09:05:17 +0530
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  3
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-bs9b6 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-bs9b6:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-bs9b6
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  79s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/javaprogram-64b48854-ns7jp to minikube
  Normal   Pulled     74s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "arunkumarduraisamy66/javacontprogram" in 3.4663937s
  Normal   Pulled     68s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "arunkumarduraisamy66/javacontprogram" in 3.5957121s
  Normal   Pulled     46s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "arunkumarduraisamy66/javacontprogram" in 3.8325583s
  Normal   Pulling    16s (x4 over 77s)  kubelet            Pulling image "arunkumarduraisamy66/javacontprogram"
  Normal   Pulled     13s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "arunkumarduraisamy66/javacontprogram" in 3.5564947s
  Normal   Created    12s (x4 over 74s)  kubelet            Created container javacontprogram
  Normal   Started    12s (x4 over 73s)  kubelet            Started container javacontprogram
  Warning  BackOff    10s (x5 over 66s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

Comment: What does `kubectl describe pod` on the pod that gets created say?

Comment: See this https://hub.docker.com/search?q=arunkumarduraisamy66&type=image

Comment: oh looks like ur image is not on docker hub

Comment: But it is present in docker hub

Comment: The events you pasted shows that it isn't an image issue (successfully pulled) but is actually an issue with the image. It's terminating (i.e., printing hello world and quitting), which is exactly what I would expect given your code. Generally pods are expected to remain running forever, hence why you see it marked as an error state.

Comment: @mmking why does it give error message as ErrImagePull

Comment: Uncertain why. The event logs doesn't indicate there were any image pull issues

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated your application's image and as mentioned in comments by @mmking it is terminated because pod has finished it's task. When you check logs of the pod you can see that it has ran correctly and printed `helloworld` 20 times and then gets terminated as there is nothing more to do for this pod:

```
$kubectl logs javakubedeployment-7bcfb44b74-8b5zz
helloworld      1
helloworld      2
helloworld      3
[...]
helloworld      19
helloworld      20
```

To keep pod running you can add simple `sleep` command in it.